# I am seeing Invalid characters during a find and replace c#

Tags: c#, replace

Newbie here, please help.
I have a text file on my PC when I read it and do a find ’ and replace it with '
After saving the file,  the replaced character looks like this: ï¿½
How can I do the find and replace to have this character ' instead of ï¿½

My code:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("C:\file.txt") ;
text = text.Replace("’", "'");
File.WriteAllText("C:", file2.txt);
```

I tried UnicodeToUTF8(text)

Comment: Your sample code is incorrect -- it doesn't write the contents of `text` anywhere. Please make sure you have actually run the code in your question, and you've made sure that it reproduces your problem. We often get questions where the code in the question doesn't actually demonstrate the problem because the asker never ran it, and it's a waste of everyone's time

Comment: `File.ReadAllText("C:\file.txt") ;` should be `File.ReadAllText("C:\\file.txt") ;` or `File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.txt") ;`. Also **don't use `C:\` as a working/scratch/temp dir, argh**.

Comment: Note that `ï¿½` is the Unicode replacement character `\uFFFD` ([see here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)), when written as UTF-8 but interpreted as ASCII (or something ASCII-like). This likely means that the file that you read wasn't using UTF-8, but you tried to interpret it as UTF-8, and the decoder didn't understand whatever byte represented `’`, and so replaced it with the replacement character. That's why your `Replace` didn't work.

Comment: To fix this, we need to understand what encoding the original file is in. There's no way to auto-detect this unfortunately. Can you run `chcp` on the command line, and tell us what it prints out?